# Filter observableArray in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

have the following view model (took some parts out)

```
function ProjectViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.openProjects = ko.observableArray();
    self.currentPhase = ko.observable();  

    self.filteredProjects = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.openProjects(), function(ProjectModel) {   
            return ProjectModel.phase == self.currentPhase();
        });
    }); 

    self.filter = function (phase) {
            self.currentPhase(phase);
    }   
}
```

I want to have a span with the total number of projects:

```
<span data-bind="text: openProjects().length + ' Projects'"></span>
```

And then I want a span for each project phase displaying the number of projects for that phase but I'm not sure how to pass the parameter on?

```
<span data-bind="text: filteredProjects().length"></span> // pass on for example 'Starting'

<span data-bind="text: filteredProjects().length"></span> // pass on for example 'Running'

<span data-bind="text: filteredProjects().length"></span> // pass on for example 'Closing'
```

in `self.filteredProjects = ko.computed(function() {`   I could simply hard code the value and repeat the code three times but there must be a nicer way of doing it? I.e. bind self.currentPhase somehow with a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a factory method to build `ko.computed`.

```
self.filteredProjects = function(phase) {
    // use currentPhase as default
    var filterPhase = phase || self.currentPhase();

    return ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.openProjects(), function(ProjectModel) {   
            return ProjectModel.phase == filterPhase;
        });
    });
};
```

This binding uses currentPhase

```
<span data-bind="text: filteredProjects()().length"></span>
```

These binding use 'Starting', 'Running' and 'Closing'

```
<span data-bind="text: filteredProjects('Starting')().length"></span>
<span data-bind="text: filteredProjects('Running')().length"></span>
<span data-bind="text: filteredProjects('Closing')().length"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition might not be matching here

```
self.filteredProjects = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.openProjects(), function(ProjectModel) {   
        return ProjectModel.phase == self.currentPhase();
    });
});
```

Try doing it like this

```
return ProjectModel.phase() == self.currentPhase();
```

If you know phase is an observable